# How to update a ListView when deleting an item in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, listview

I have a ListView in a Fragment that uses a custom adaptor to create a to do list. Each task in the list has a coloured canvas circle that can be checked or unchecked. I want it so that after 3 seconds of checking a task it will see if it is still checked and if it is, it will then remove that task from the list. My deleteTask function in my ToDoListAdaptor will remove the task from the ArrayList that holds the tasks and will then call notifyDataSetChanged() however this does nothing to update the view itself, it still shows no change. Do I need to throw in funky magic because the ListView is in a Fragment? Or am I missing something simple?

ToDoListFragment.kt

```
class ToDoListFragment : Fragment()
{
    //lateinits for XML objects
    lateinit var toDoList : ListView

    // other Lateinits
    private lateinit var currentContext : Context
    lateinit var temps : ArrayList<Task>
    lateinit var adaptor : ToDoListAdaptor


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View?
    {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_to_do_list, container, false)

        setXMLObjects(v)

        return v
    }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)

        currentContext = context
    }

    private fun setXMLObjects(v : View)
    {
        toDoList = v.findViewById(R.id.ToDoList)

        // temp tasks
        temps = ArrayList(4)
        temps.add(Task("kick ass", "Desc1", ContextCompat.getColor(currentContext, R.color.blue)))
        temps.add(Task("chew bubblegum", "Desc2", ContextCompat.getColor(currentContext, R.color.green)))
        temps.add(Task("get a freaken job", "Desc3", ContextCompat.getColor(currentContext, R.color.purple)))
        temps.add(Task("become the next Elon Musk", "Desc4", ContextCompat.getColor(currentContext, R.color.red)))

        adaptor = ToDoListAdaptor(currentContext, temps)

        toDoList.adapter = adaptor
        adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

And my ToDoListAdaptor

```
// extends the BaseAdaptor class
class ToDoListAdaptor(private val context: Context, private val taskArrayList : ArrayList<Task>) : BaseAdapter()
{
    private val inflater: LayoutInflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater


    //*************************** Override Base adaptors functions *****************************************
    override fun getCount(): Int
    {
        return taskArrayList.size
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any
    {
        return taskArrayList[position]
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long
    {
        return position.toLong()
    }

    // this is called for each item in the list
    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View
    {
        val task = taskArrayList[position]
        // Get the view associated with the list item at position
        //val rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.task, parent, false)
        val rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.task, parent, false)

        val taskName = rowView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.TaskName)
        taskName.text = task.getName()

        val taskImageButton = rowView.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.TaskCompletedImageButton)
        rowView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener { setCanvases(position, taskImageButton)}

        taskImageButton.setOnClickListener { checkTask(taskImageButton, position) }


        return rowView
    }

    //*************************** End of Override Base adaptors functions ***********************************

    fun getTaskName(position : Int) : String
    {
        return taskArrayList[position].getName()
    }

    fun getTaskDescription(position : Int) : String
    {
        return taskArrayList[position].getDescription()
    }

    fun getTaskColour(position : Int) : Int
    {
        return taskArrayList[position].getColour()
    }

    private fun setCanvases(position : Int, image : ImageButton)
    {
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image.width, image.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)

        image.background = BitmapDrawable(bitmap)

        val canvasPaint = Paint()
        canvasPaint.color = taskArrayList[position].getColour()
        canvasPaint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        canvasPaint.strokeWidth = 10F
        canvasPaint.isAntiAlias = true

        canvas.drawCircle(image.width / 2f, image.height / 2f, min(image.width * 0.45f, image.height * 0.45f), canvasPaint)
    }

    private fun checkTask(image : ImageView, position : Int)
    {
        if( ! taskArrayList[position].isChecked())
        {
            taskArrayList[position].checkUncheck()

            val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image.width, image.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
            val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)

            image.background = BitmapDrawable(bitmap)

            val canvasPaint = Paint()
            canvasPaint.color = taskArrayList[position].getColour()
            canvasPaint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
            canvasPaint.strokeWidth = 10F
            canvasPaint.isAntiAlias = true

            val canvasPaint2 = Paint()
            canvasPaint2.color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.black)
            canvasPaint2.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
            canvasPaint2.strokeWidth = 10F
            canvasPaint2.isAntiAlias = true

            val checkMarkPoint = floatArrayOf(
                image.width * 0.25f, image.height * 0.4f, image.width * 0.35f, image.height * 0.75f,
                image.width * 0.35f, image.height * 0.75f, image.width * 0.85f, image.height * 0.1f
            )

            canvas.drawCircle(
                image.width / 2f,
                image.height / 2f,
                min(image.width * 0.45f, image.height * 0.45f),
                canvasPaint
            )
            canvas.drawLines(checkMarkPoint, canvasPaint2)

            val dThread = DeleteThread(position)
            dThread.start()
        }
        else
        {
            taskArrayList[position].checkUncheck()

            val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image.width, image.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
            val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)

            image.background = BitmapDrawable(bitmap)

            val canvasPaint = Paint()
            canvasPaint.color = taskArrayList[position].getColour()
            canvasPaint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
            canvasPaint.strokeWidth = 10F
            canvasPaint.isAntiAlias = true

            canvas.drawCircle(
                image.width / 2f,
                image.height / 2f,
                min(image.width * 0.45f, image.height * 0.45f),
                canvasPaint
            )
        }
    }

    private fun deleteTask(position : Int)
    {
        taskArrayList.removeAt(position)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    private inner class DeleteThread(private var position: Int) : Thread()
    {
        override fun run()
        {
            try
            {
                sleep(3000)

                if(taskArrayList[position].isChecked())
                {
                    deleteTask(position)
                }
            }
            catch(exception : Exception)
            {
               print(exception.message)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `RecyclerView` and `RecyclerView.Adapter`, so you'll be easily able to use `notifyItemRemoved(position)` method when your `checkTask(taskImageButton, position)` is done. Also it will only notify the item that needs to be updated, it's not the case with notifyDataSetChanged since it's notify all data.

Answer (score 1):

when we call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, it refreshes the whole list. As a result, `getView()` is called for every item on the list.
the best thing you should use [**RecyclerView ListAdapter**](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter) and its method DiffUtil is the secret ingredient that makes it possible for ListAdapter to change the items in the list efficiently. DiffUtil compares the new list with the old list to figure out what was **added, moved, and removed** and outputs a list of update operations that convert the first list into the second efficiently.